# Creating arrays in a for loop via list()?

Tags: php, arrays

$$I have a bunch fo text files I'd like to eventually explode into arrays, but since the amount of text files is dynamically chosen via user input, I can't just initialize them one-by-one and instead am opting for a for loop.

For the sake of example, three text files I have contain the following (excuse the \n, imagine it's a line break):

> file1.txt = 1 \n 2 \n 3
>
> file2.txt = 6 \n 2 \n 7
>
> file3.txt = 9 \n 1 \n 9

The code I attempted:

```
<?php
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
        list($line1[$i], $line2[$i], $line3[$i]) = file("public_html/texts/file".$i.".txt");
?>
```

This obviously doesn't work, but I'm not sure why. In the end, the result should be:

```
$line1[1] = 1
$line2[1] = 2
$line3[1] = 3
$line1[2] = 6
$line2[2] = 2
$line3[2] = 7
$line1[3] = 9
$line2[3] = 1
$line3[3] = 9
```

How do I go about doing this?

edit; fixed typo.

Comment: Your code seems right, the error must be elsewhere not your use of list(). Have you checked the file is correctly read and returned by file() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {

    $lines = file('public_html/texts/file' . $i . '.txt');

    $line1[] = $lines[0];
    $line2[] = $lines[1];
    $line3[] = $lines[2];
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really see it here. This takes into consideration only file1.txt and file2.txt, but the amount of text files is user defined and can be any number.

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in your code, see:

```
file("public_html/texts/file".&i.".txt");
                              ^-- TYPO HERE
```

Comment: See my comment to your question above, your error should be elsewhere, you seem to be running php with no error logging, otherwise the above typo would cause a PHP parse error that you would have seen. So first enable php error output so you see the errors in your code.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I really appreciate it. I do have error logging, and the error I get in WAMP is that any var I try to echo doesn't exist. When I echo say, $line1[1], it says it is undefined.